# How mapping many-to-many with additional columes in NHibernate

Tags: c#, xml, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

Please I do not know how to map "projekt_etapa" see on picture. it is Many to many, but I have there some another columes. So I do not know If i have tu use bag or make class for it. thank you so mutch.

[image: My DB what i have to map]

Comment: possible duplicate of [nhibernate many-to-many mapping - additional column in the mapping table?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/889513/nhibernate-many-to-many-mapping-additional-column-in-the-mapping-table)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is definitely a duplicate of several other questions on StackOverflow.  These are 3 of the many.

[nhibernate many-to-many mapping - additional column in the mapping table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/889513/nhibernate-many-to-many-mapping-additional-column-in-the-mapping-table)
[additional fields in NHibernate many-to-many relation tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166426/additional-fields-in-nhibernate-many-to-many-relation-tables)
[Fluent Nhibernate Many-to-Many mapping with extra column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2455473/fluent-nhibernate-many-to-many-mapping-with-extra-column)

Brought to you by google:
site:StackOverflow.com nhibernate many to many additional columns