# Fluent NHibernate Mapping Compent with Many-To-Many and Extra Fields

Tags: nhibernate, dictionary, components, fluent

I have been spinning around in the same place trying to figure this issue with a many-to-many table with extra columns. I am swallowing my pride and asking more experienced Fluent NHibernate  experts if you can help out here.

I have been trying to use a component for a many-to-many table but I don't seem to find where to point the component to cause a join on a specific column. I guess as long as I populate the completion information object, the presence and usage of a component is not a requirement for me.

This is my simplified schema.

```
User
...................
Id
Name 

Task
...................
Id
Name


Job
...................
Id
Name

JobTask
...................
JobId
TaskId
CompletedByUserId
CompletionDate
CompletionNotes
```

Then I have objects like so:

```
 public class Job
 {
    long Id { get; set; }
    IList<Task> Tasks { get; set; }
 }


 public class Task
 {
    long Id { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }
    CompletionInfo CompletionInfo { get; set; }
 }

 public class CompletionInfo
 {
    User User { get; set; }
    DateTime CompletionDate { get; set; }
 }
```

Can you help with your ideas how to implement this in fluent nhibernate?

I had this mapping before on the JobMap and it would work but only for the many-to-many columns ( TaskId, JobId). I need the extra information related to that relationship(dateCompleted, userCompleted,etc)

```
 HasManyToMany<Task>(job => job.Tasks)
            .Table(ManyToManyTable)
             .ParentKeyColumn("JobId")
            .ChildKeyColumn("TaskId")
            .Not.LazyLoad()
            .Cascade.Delete();
```

In order to simplify things with the many-to many I thought to create an object to represent the relationship and encapsulate a task. Like so:
And I would add a proxy in the Job task to modify the actual Task properties. But that is not going anywhere.

This must be something common out there, I am very surprised there not much regarding this issue. 
Naturally I would have loved a way to extend the HasManyToMany but not sure how, hence this post.

```
public class JobTask : Entity<long, JobTask>
{ 
    public virtual Job ParentJob { get; set; }

    public virtual Task Task   { set;set; }

    public virtual TaskCompletionDetails CompletionInformation
    {
        get
        {
            if (this.Task == null)
                return null;

            return Task.CompletionInformation;
        }

        set
        {
            if (this.Task == null)
                return;

            this.Task.CompletionInformation = value;
        }
    }


    public virtual string CompletionNotes
    {
        get
        {
            if (this.Task == null || this.Task.CompletionInformation == null)
                return null;

            return Task.CompletionInformation.Notes;
        }

        set
        {
            if (this.Task == null)
                return;

            this.Task.CompletionInformation.Notes = value;
        }
    }

    public virtual DateTime? CompletionDate
    {
        get
        {
            if (this.Task == null || this.Task.CompletionInformation == null)
                return null;

            return Task.CompletionInformation.Date;
        }

        set
        {
            if (this.Task == null)
                return;

            this.Task.CompletionInformation.Date = value;
        }
    }

    public virtual IUser User
    {
        get
        {
            if (this.Task == null || this.Task.CompletionInformation == null)
                return null;

            return Task.CompletionInformation.User;
        }

        set
        {
            if (this.Task == null || value == null)
                return;

            if (this.Task.CompletionInformation != null)
                this.Task.CompletionInformation.User = value;
        }
       }
    }
 }
```

This would be the map direction I have started for it:

```
public class JobTaskMap : ClassMap<JobTask>
{
    private const string ModelTable = "[JobTasks]";

    public JobTaskMap()
    {
        Table(ModelTable);

        Id(jobTask => jobTask.Id)
            .Column("Id")
            .GeneratedBy.Identity();

        References<Job>( jobTask => jobTask.ParentJob)
            .Column("JobId")
            .Fetch.Join();

        Component<Task>( jobTask => (Task) jobTask.Task,
                // This is the task
                 comp =>
                 { 
                     // This is the task completion information
                     comp.Component<TaskCompletionDetails>(
                         task => (TaskCompletionDetails)task.CompletionInformation,
                         compInfo =>
                         {    
                             compInfo.Map(info => info.Date)
                                .Column("CompletionDate")
                                .Nullable();

                             compInfo.Map(info => info.Notes)
                                .Column("CompletionNotes")
                                .Nullable();

                             compInfo.References<User>(info => info.User)
                                .Column("CompletedByUserId")
                                .Nullable()
                                .Fetch.Join();
                         });  
                 });

    }
```

These are some other related reading I have followed without success:

Reference:

http://wiki.fluentnhibernate.org/Fluent_mapping

[Fluent Nhibernate Many-to-Many mapping with extra column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2455473/fluent-nhibernate-many-to-many-mapping-with-extra-column)

Answer (score 1):

heres a way which depends on the id generation strategy used. if `Identity` is used then this won't do (at least NH discourages use of Identity for various reasons), but with every strategy that inserts the id itself it would work:

```
class JobMap : ClassMap<Job>
{
    public JobMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id);

        HasMany(x => x.Tasks)
            .KeyColumn("JobId");
    }
}

class TaskMap : ClassMap<Task>
{
    public TaskMap()
    {
        Table("JobTask");
        Id(x => x.Id, "TaskId");

        Component(x => x.CompletionInfo, c =>
        {
            c.Map(x => x.CompletionDate);
            c.References(x => x.User, "CompletedByUserId");
        });

        Join("Task", join =>
        {
            join.Map(x => x.Name, "Name");
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Firo. I will check this and see if it fixes my issue. I had tried using a compositeId and I am getting a bunch of NonUniqueObjectException-s.